# ssh: pgbarman setup issues in Amazon-EC2 & Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have two servers, one in Amazon EC2 instance (t1.medium) and another in Microsoft Azure (medium) instance. Both these servers have the same config `Ubuntu LTS 12.04.1, 64-bit arch` running `PostgreSQL 9.1`. I need to setup disaster recovery system on Azure (turn on WAL archiving for the Amazon instance's Database for my specific schedules of data backups via `pgbarman`).

While going through the [pgbarman-docs](http://docs.pgbarman.org/), one of the mandatory requirements is thaat,

- `ssh` communication required on both ends without password authentication/prompt. (`Pgbarman` has a pre-requisite to have `postgres@amazon` to `ssh` directly to `barman@azure` and vice-versa. See, [Getting started with Pgbarman](http://docs.pgbarman.org/#getting_started)).

But my complexities for logging to these instances are below:

- Amazon EC2 has a `.pem` file which can be accessed without any password authentication: `ssh -i my-pem-file.pem ubuntu@my-instance-public-ip-region.compute.amazonaws.com`
- Azure doesn't has a `.pem` file. Instead, it can be accessed with a password mechanism: `ssh azure-user@app.cloudapp.net`

Still, to enable the setup I did the below,

- I created a key file `postgres-barman.pub` via `ssh-keygen` from `barman@azure`.
- Transferred this file to Amazon via `ssh-copy-id -i ubuntu@amazon` (See below links for more information)

My problems are:

1. **ssh Azure to Amazon:**

   - I cannot transfer this file to `postgres` user: 
     `cat postgres-barman.pub | ssh -i my-pem-file.pem postgres@amazon 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'` but if I change destination's user to `ubuntu`, the file gets copied.
   - After transferring the file (via `ubuntu` user), I try to do this: `ssh postgres@amazon`. It fails.
2. **ssh Amazon to Azure**

   - The same file is now residing on both sides. Still, if I issue `ssh barman@azure`, it asks for a password authentication (which is set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the Azure instance). I cannot proceed with this die to `barman` pre-req.
3. Amazon allows to be `ssh`ed only via `ubuntu` user. I need to be enable this for `postgres` user. Can this be done?

Note: Amazon has `PasswordAuthentication` set to `no` in it's `sshd_config` file.

References:

- ssh-copy-id:

  - [Ubuntu SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys),
  - [3 steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) and
  - [SSH-in-Linux](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Comment: There are guides on the azure site itself on how to set up key-based ssh logins (you need to wrap the key in X.509, but there are step-by-step guides). You obviously can't write to another user's home directory - that would be a horrible security hole. Use su/sudo to copy the keyfiles on the linux side. Don't forget to set ownership + permissions appropriately.

Comment: You can also use SSH authentication with Azure VMs, just like EC2, FYI. If creating via REST or an SDK, there are parameters for that; if you are creating in the portal, make sure to use the more advanced creation option instead of "Quick Create" to be able to upload the .pem file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, I got it sorted out.

I wasn't doing the configuration properly. This is what I did.

On Amazon:

```
ubuntu@amazon~$ sudo -s
root@amazon~$ passwd postgres
Enter new UNIX Password:
ubuntu@amazon~$ su - postgres
Password:
postgres@amazon~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
postgres@amazon~$ scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub barman@azure-ip:~/.ssh/
```

On Azure:

```
ubuntu@azure~$ sudo -s
root@azure~$ passwd barman
Enter new UNIX Password:
ubuntu@azure~$ su - barman
Password:
barman@azure~$ cd .ssh
barman@azure~$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, ssh to azure:

```
postgres@amazon:~$ ssh barman@azure
```

Now, repeat the same for Azure.

Only difference was that, the key transfer to Amazon wasn't happening via `scp`. So, I copied the contents from `id_rsa.pub` in barman@azure's `/.ssh` folder, pasted in postgres@amazon's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file and saved it.

Now, ssh to amazon:

```
barman@azure:~$ ssh postgres@amazon
```

It works! Thanks for the advice!

References:

- [Switch user in Linux/Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-switch-between-users-on-one-terminal)
- [Barman-setup-explained](http://ostryalabs.com/blog/2012/12/08/barman-postgresql.html)

Now to worry about barman' cronjob.